# Ignoring a word in regex (negative lookahead)

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I'm looking to try and ignore a word in regex, but the solutions I've seen here did not work correctly for me.

[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

The issue I'm facing is I have an existing regex:

`(?P<MovieCode>[A-Za-z]{3,6}-\d{3,5})(?P<MoviePart>[A-C]{1}\b)?`

That is matching on Deku-041114-575-boku.mp4.

However, I want this regex to fail to match for cases where the MovieCode group has Deku in it.

I tried
`(?P<MovieCode>(?!Deku)[A-Za-z]{3,6}-\d{3,5})(?P<MoviePart>[A-C]{1}\b)?`
but unfortunately it just matches eku-124 and I need it to fail.

I have a regex101 with my attempts.
https://regex101.com/r/xqALM2/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MovieClose group can match 3-6 chars A-Z and Deku has 4 chars. If that part should not contain Deku, you could use the negative lookahead predeced by repeating 0+ times a character class `[A-Za-z]*` as it can not cross the `-`.

To prevent matching `eku-124`, you could prepend a word boundary before the MovieClose group or add `(?<!\S` if there should be a whitespace boundary at the left.

Note that you can omit `{1}` from the pattern.

```
\b(?P<MovieCode>(?![A-Za-z]*Deku)[A-Za-z]{3,6}-\d{3,5})(?P<MoviePart>[A-C]\b)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DyLFMP/1)

Comment: Thank you! I've been battling this for a day now. I would have never thought to do it like this. The word boundary at the beginning was great as well. 

If I need to expand the "ignored" word to be more than one, I could just do:

`\b(?P<MovieCode>(?![A-Za-z]*(Deku|Boku))[A-Za-z]{3,6}-\d{3,5})(?P<MoviePart>[A-C]\b)?`

right?

Comment: @bittermelonman That is correct, if you don't need the capture group, you could make it non capturing `(?:Deku|Boku)`